# How to override DataContextProperty metadata in non static constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I need to override the metadata of the DataContextProperty in my ContentControl to associate a PropertyChangedCallback.

As i know this is only allowed in the static constructor, but the PropertyChangedCallback can't be a static function.
Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

static cunstructor:

```
static ListAndDetailsControl() {    
DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListAndDetailsControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
}
```

function that should be called on property changed:

```
private void OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverrideMetadata` must not be mandatory in a static constructor(but it should be there). You can put it e.g. in `Button.Click` event handler.

> PropertyChangedCallback can't be a static function

It's wrong. PropertyChangedCallback can be a static function.

The problem is that if somebody has already registered/overridden the metadata for the property, then you will get an exception.

See on [MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-override-metadata-for-a-dependency-property)

> Also, metadata **can only be overridden once** per type. Subsequent
>   attempts to override metadata on the same type will raise an
>   exception.

To track changes on DataContext just use appropriate event `ContentControl.DataContextChanged`.

```
<ContentControl DataContextChanged="OnDataContextChanged">
```

To avoid a code behind use a behavior handling `DataContextChanged`.

Comment: I'm a giddy goat. Of course PropertyChangedCallback can be static. My mistake sry.